# JQuery. Показывать и скрывать блоки по кругу

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, циклы

У меня есть 6 блоков div. Изначально они скрыты. Нужно показать первый div, через секунду второй, потом третий и т.д.

Задача в том, чтобы показывать length-1 (на один меньше общего количества) элементов и при появлении пятого (предпоследнего) первый скрывать, а после появления шестого снова показывается первый, потом второй и так далее по бесконечному кругу:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var delay = 0,
        notes = $('.b-notification');

    notes.each(function() {
        var note = $(this);

        setInterval(function() {
            note.addClass('show');
        }, delay+=1000);
    });


});
```

```css
.b-notification {
  display: none;
}

.b-notification.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b-notification">1</div>
<div class="b-notification">2</div>
<div class="b-notification">3</div>
<div class="b-notification">4</div>
<div class="b-notification">5</div>
<div class="b-notification">6</div>
```

https://codepen.io/astrolavrov/pen/XWWxOqX

На кодпене смог сделать добавление класса .show с периодом в одну секунду. Но не получается зациклить этот код.

Comment: Вы вот здесь что-то забыли сделать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/950847/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var index = 0, maxShow = 4,
    notes = $('.b-notification');

  setInterval(function() {
    var note = notes.eq(index);
    note.addClass('show');
    if (notes.filter('.show').length > maxShow) {
      note.parent().append(note);
      $('.b-notification.show').eq(0).removeClass('show');
    }
    index = ++index % notes.length;
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.b-notification {
  display: none;
}

.b-notification.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b-notification">1</div>
<div class="b-notification">2</div>
<div class="b-notification">3</div>
<div class="b-notification">4</div>
<div class="b-notification">5</div>
<div class="b-notification">6</div>
```

Comment: а как повернуть цикл наоборот? Чтобы сначала появлялся последний элемент, затем предыдущий НАД НИМ и так далее, а в конце цикла нижний скрывать и переносить его вврех? Заранее спасибо

Comment: @Slavrov Вы уже попробовали сделать это сами?

Comment: если честно, то задача развернуть цикл уже неактуальна, но я всё равно попробовал. Чуть лучше разобравшись с вашим кодом понял, что показывать блоки нужно не с начала (index), а с конца и делать не аппенд, а препенд. Но код не сохранил. Вам ещё раз спасибо!